# Google analytics API gapi - SORT by visitCount wrong way

Tags: api, sorting, google-analytics

I have a little problem, i use the gapi class to get information from google analytics.

The problem is when i sorting by the dimensions: **visitCount** it's sort like this:

1,10,11,12,2,3,4,5,50,6,7,8,9

I don't understand, because if i sort by for example: **visits** its sorts right, like up to 10 by 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10,11

And i've also tried to desort like: **-visitCount** it still does the same just the other way.

Anyone that know what the problem is?, or is it Google that don't allow it?

and my code is simple, there is nothing to see: **define('sort', 'visitCount');**

Answer (score 1):

This is because [ga:visitCount](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets/visitor#ga%3avisitCount) is a Dimension and as such is treated as a string (i.e. text). Whereas [ga:visits](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets/session#ga%3avisits) is a Metric and is treated as a number.

In the case of ***ga:visitCount***, when you sort numbers that are represented as a string you will get the order that you have described. 1, 10, 11, 12, 2 and so on. This is the actual correct sorting for strings/text. To fix this you would first need to convert these to numbers (integers) and then sort or carry out some other applicable solution.